# Securing certain parts of an application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, security

If someone logs on to my application this user contains a dictionary with certain permissions.

```
ex: module.view.workspace = true
    module.view.reporting = false
    ...
```

Then we know to what parts of the application the user has access.
What I want to know is how we can apply these permissions on the view.
We are working in an AS 3 (FLEX) environment.

This is what we came up with so far (but I wanna have an idea of other possibilities).
We have a modelLocator storing the loggedOnUser (which contains it's permissions).
these permissions are added to a permissionObject in the modellocator.
We Create a SecurityManager class that has a function called hasAccess("permission").
This object will check the PermissionObject in the modellocator and return true/false.
In the view we just check if the user has access and then show the control.

```
If (SecurityManager.hasAccess("module.view.workspace") {
     // code that generates the workspace;
}
```

I just don't know if this is the best practice.
Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is basically valid.  I would recommend defining a class with static const that map to your different permissions and referencing that:

```
SecurityManager.hasAccess(SecurityManager.MODULE_VIEW_WORKSPACE)
```

This will save you a lot of manual search/replace work if you start to change the names of your permission items.

Answer (score 0):

Sem,

I have a similar method and it worked fine so far. My application is written in C#.NET but the method is still valid. Since mine is a WinForms application I have to do other stuff but basically there is at some point an If statement asking that very same "question".

Martin.